# Find all subtypes of an object type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an object type defined as  `NOT FINAL` in oracle.  I'd like to find out all the subtypes of this type.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this from the tables [ALL_TYPES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2111.htm#i1593078) or [USER_TYPES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4483.htm#i1635769) with the column `SUPERTYPE_NAME` :

> **SUPERTYPE_NAME**    `VARCHAR2(30)`
>   *Name of the supertype (NULL if type is not a subtype)*

The `SUPERTYPE_NAME` being **not** `NULL` is precisely what you are looking for.

---

Example with the standard type used by Oracle in execution plans :

```
SELECT TYPE_NAME,  SUPERTYPE_OWNER ,  SUPERTYPE_NAME ,  FINAL    
FROM SYS.ALL_TYPES
WHERE  SUPERTYPE_NAME ='SQL_PLAN_ROW_TYPE'
```

Results

```
TYPE_NAME                       SUPERTYPE_OWNER     SUPERTYPE_NAME          FINAL
SQL_PLAN_ALLSTAT_ROW_TYPE       SYS                 SQL_PLAN_ROW_TYPE       NO 
SQL_PLAN_STAT_ROW_TYPE          SYS                 SQL_PLAN_ROW_TYPE       YES
```

The 2 rows are a subtype of `SQL_PLAN_ROW_TYPE`

---

Note that `ALL_TYPES` lists all objects types in the DB. You should use `USER_TYPES` instead to get only those that you created

If you want all your custom types that are subtypes, you can thus do this :

```
SELECT TYPE_NAME,  SUPERTYPE_OWNER ,  SUPERTYPE_NAME ,  FINAL    
FROM SYS.USER_TYPES
WHERE  SUPERTYPE_NAME IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY SUPERTYPE_OWNER ,  SUPERTYPE_NAME, FINAL, TYPE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the `user_types` view (or [`all_types`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2127.htm#REFRN20298), or `dba_types`, if you aren't the owner). For example, to just get the subtype names:

```
select type_name
from user_types
where supertype_name = 'YOUR_TYPE_NAME';
```

There's lot of other interesting information in that view though. If you use the ALL or DBA views you may want to filter on both `owner` and `supertype_owner`.